# Use 8 individual border images instead of border-image in CSS

Tags: image, css, border

I've been provided with 8 individual images (top left, top, top right etc) for a border around the main (fixed width) content box. If I was given a single image, I'd use [border-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp).

What's the best way to use the 8 images? Divs with absolute positioning? Or is it such a pain I should just combine them into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's so hard about combining the images into one? It has numerous other advantages, like reducing the number of HTTP requests the client needs to make, for example.

An alternative is to use CSS3's multiple background image feature, where you'd set each image as a layer in your box.

Comment: Not super hard, so that's what I ended up doing with paint.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Eric Myer used a technique whereby (just to explain technique) the image was a little circle. Then, that was the background graphic in four separate divs each abs positioned in the corners of a containing div w/relative position. Background position was changed for each and a regular border was used for the straight lines in effect getting rounded corners. The circle had to be filled with white or whatever bckgrnd color you used.

This way, one could expand. You still need to have the height expand should changes occur, right?

I'd make one for the top and bottom and a third that repeats on the Y for the middle, that way your box will expand if content is added. Height that is.